# How to make stepper in flutter like this

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to make a stepper similar to the above. However, Flutter doesn't have padding or margin to set position. How can I make such a stepper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: [another_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/another_stepper)

You can create a list of your steps and then you can directly make stepper in horizontal and vertical direction with ease.